# Consumer group Load balanced readers

Tags: azure-eventhub

I am doing some POC to use EventHub, i do have  multiple instances for a consumer and  expect only one of the instance will receive the event, i tried both EventHubClient and EventProcessorHost is there any way i can make it possible. Kafka has a similar support for Load balanced consumer based on consumer group https://kafka.apache.org/intro.html#intro_consumers. I always get an error saying

```
New receiver with higher epoch of '4' is created hence current receiver with epoch '3' is getting disconnected.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the host name which i registered was same for every instance, Now i have changed to use different host name per instance using UUID Random as hostname while constructing the EventProcessorHost class